# How to run azure function quarter of first month and quarter of last month

Tags: c#

I have written one program but I need to run azure function each quarter of first months and last month of quarter.

Comment: Do you want it to execute once each quarter or do you want it to report over a quarter (a 3 month time window per report)?

Comment: Every quarter of first months 1st day and Every quarter of last month 1st day.

Comment: Your description of when you want to run this is unclear and inconsistent across your question and your comments on answers. I recommend to give examples. Maybe just list all times in a sample year when you want it executed.

Comment: "each quarter of first months" reads like 4 times in January. "last month of quarter" reads like every day in March, June, September and December. "every quarter of first months first weekend" reads like twice on first Saturday and twice on first Sunday in January. "quarter of first month and quarter of last months" reads like January 1st to January 8th and December 1st to December 8th.

Answer (score 1):

For a Scheduled Azure Function, you can set up a [CRON expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions) to specify when it should be executed.

This CRON expression takes several values in the form

> {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}

So this will execute on the 1st of every quarter (January, April, July, October), at midnight:

> 0 0 0 1 1,4,7,10 *

A month-expression `*/3` will execute every three months, but (possibly) on months 3, 6, 9 and 12

---

To fire every Saturday at (for example) 1AM (01:00), you can use this:

> 0 0 1 * * Sat

But then your code would need to check whether "now" is the first or last Saturday of the quarter and just exit if it is not.

Comment: Please help me for every quarter of first months first weekend and every quarter of last months last weekend.

Comment: @Arshadwarsi I am not sure that it is possible to specify "first" or "last" Saturday (as startday of the weekend). Maybe fire *every* Saturday (use the day-of-week field) and then check in your code whether it is the first or last of your quarter?

Answer (score 1):

Use this CRON expression to run your function at 12:00 AM, on day 1 of the month, every 3 months.

> 0 0 1 */3 *

Your scheduled Azure function declaration will look like that:

```cs
public static class MyFunctionThatShouldRunQuarterly
{
  [FunctionName(nameof(MyFunctionThatShouldRunQuarterly))]
  public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 1 */3 *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger externalLogger) 
  {
     // your code goes here     
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi i need to run above program quarter of first month and quarter of last months. please give me solution